# Vectors - Scalar equation of a plane

Tags: vectors, 3d, orthogonality, plane-curves, plane-geometry

Find the scalar equation of the plane that is orthogonal to the curve parameterised by $x(t)=t^3,\ y(t)=t^2,\ z(t) = t$ 
at the point where $t=-1$

Write your equation in the form $ax+by+cz=k$ where $(a, b, c)$ is a unit vector.

---

I began by finding the coordinate on the curve at the point $t = -1$, which is $(-1, 1, -1)$.

Don't we need to be given a normal vector? which I could dot with the point $(-1, 1, -1)$ to get my constant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tangent vector to the curve at $t=-1$ is $\mathbf{T}=\left(x'(-1),y'(-1),z'(-1))\right)=\ldots =(3,-2,1)$ or $\mathbf{t}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{14}}(3,-2,1)$ (unitary). Now, our plane is $$\frac{3}{\sqrt{14}}(x+1)+\frac{-2}{\sqrt{14}}(y-1)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{14}}(z+1)=0\Leftrightarrow\ldots$$

Comment: Why did you differentiate the points on the curve to find the coordinates?

Comment: To find a tangent vector to de curve.

Comment: Ok I see, so that's the final answer? the constant = 0? Also what is the name of this particular topic?

Comment: The final answer $\frac{3}{\sqrt{14}}x+\frac{-2}{\sqrt{14}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{14}}z=-\frac{6}{\sqrt{14}}=0.$ I don't know what you mean by "what is the name of this particular topic?".

Comment: I've studied vectors and planes but I have never come across curves, and that we need to differentiate to find a tangent vector to the curve. Why do you have " = −6/√14 = 0"?

Comment: To your first question: it is a well-known result. Have a look at your notes. To the second question: the problem says to write the plane in the form: $ax+by+cd=k$, so ...

Comment: Ok so is k = −6/√14 or is k = 0? sorry I'm just a bit confused.

Comment: $k=-6/\sqrt{14}$.